# EGit Push tag broken

Tags: tags, egit

I can push a tag, but not using `Push Tag...` from the `Tags` item in the `Git Repositories` view.

1. Right-click on `Tags`
2. Choose `Create Tag...`
3. Entered the Tag name, Tag message and selected the commit using the `Advanced` button.
4. Choose `OK`
5. With the `Tags` folder expanded, right-click on the newly created tag and choose `Push Tag...`
6. `Configured remote repository` is already set, so I choose `Next`
7. `CTRL` + `SPACE` to bring up the list of remotes. (I get `refs/heads/master`)
8. Select `Finish`

I get: `rejected non-fast-forward`.
I've also tried configuring push with `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Push Tag...* wizard is much too complicated at the moment, yes. Try entering `refs/tags/<nameofyourtag>` as the target ref name.

In EGit 3.2 (to be released in December 2013), the wizard is much nicer, see the [screenshot](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=237886) from the [associated bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341076).

Comment: ...Thought it was probably just the ref name I had wrong. Thank you.